# Calling static autoloaded class without namespace

Tags: php, oop, static, namespaces

I was wondering if it's possible to use a static PHP class (or a method of that class, should I say) without calling it via the namespace ala laravel?

I realise this is conflicting with the nature of namespaces, but I was mainly wanting to use them the same as Laravel does, where I can just call `Example::method('test')` rather than `\example\example\Example::method('test')`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At the top of your file, declare a use statement which creates an alias:

```
use example\example\Example;

Example::method('test'); //resolves to example\example\Example::('test')
```

You can even use a different name with 'as':

```
use example\example\Example as MyAlias;

MyAlias::method('test'); //resolves to example\example\Example::('test')
```

See http://php.net/manual/en/language.namespaces.importing.php for more information.

Note: This is not how laravel facades work but I think it is what you are looking for. If you want something more automatic then aliasing you will have to incorporate some logic into your autoloader.

Comment: Yeah this is what I was looking for.... I think. I'm a bit confused myself after reading my question 2 years later - Clearly didn't know left from right back then